# QfeCheck for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Does anyone know if there is an equivalent utility for verifying installed updates in Windows 7 [like there was for XP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19039)

This qfecheck will also warn when an update is [not installed properly and needs re-installing](http://www.theeldergeek.com/using_qfecheck.htm).

I just ran it on my XP laptop and sure enough it [flagged kb2509553](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms11-030) as needing re-installed.

Or does Windows 7 not need one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be no direct equivalent for Windows 7, but I don't think it is needed.

- For a nice GUI-based overview, you can use **Currently installed updates** in

  > Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features > Installed Updates
- If you need a command-line tool to enumerate all installed updates, you can use the [Deployment Image Servicing and Management (DISM)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744256(v=ws.10)):

  ```
  Dism /online /Get-Packages
  ```
- To check installed updates, you can use the [System Update Readiness Tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947821/en-us):

  > #### What does the System Update Readiness Tool do?
  >
  > The System Update Readiness Tool verifies the integrity of the following resources:
  >
  > - Files that are located under the following directories:
  >
  >   - %SYSTEMROOT%\Servicing\Packages
  >   - %SYSTEMROOT%\WinSxS\Manifests
  > - Registry data that is located under the following registry subkeys:
  >
  >   - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Components
  >   - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Schema
  >   - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing
  >
  > **Note** This list may be updated at any time.
  >
  > When the System Update Readiness Tool detects incorrect manifests, files, or registry data, it might replace the incorrect data with a corrected version.

Comment: I assume W7 does a better job of verifing packages are installed correctly when installing the update itself, but cannot find any supporting articles. I also assume W7 fixed this issue and no longer needs a QFE tool, I suppose SUR does this but there is no statement from microsoft specifically stating it does.

Comment: Accepting answer, but was not what I was looking for when bounty was alive.

Answer (score 1):

A tool that can check system status and security holes is
[Microsoft Baseline Security Analyzer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7558) :

> The Microsoft Baseline Security Analyzer provides a streamlined method
>   to identify missing security updates and common security
>   misconfigurations.

It is unknown to what degree does MBSA check already-installed patches.

You can also verify the correctness
of system files by using the built-in [System File Checker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_File_Checker) (SFC).

If SFC fails, and a an installation DVD that is fully slip-streamed with all patches is available,
one can still
[run SFC in offline mode](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/run-sfc-offline-windows-7-vista/).

Comment: "*you can verify the correctness*" How? And why do I need an installation DVD?

Comment: SFC is the 1st tool a sysadmin will use when system corruptness is suspected. It verifies system files against the DVD and can roll them back to their released state. It's not something one uses daily - I mentioned it only so we can have in this post the complete list of tools.

Comment: DVD not needed with Windows 7 SFC, any patches applied replace older SCF files used for replacement, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Moab: Correct: In Win7 the DVD is only required if SFC fails. In this case one [runs SFC in offline mode](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/run-sfc-offline-windows-7-vista/). I clarified my post.